# Interaction between main flex application and component

Tags: apache-flex, components, flex4

I made a login component for my flex 4 application, and i load this component from my main flex application with:

```
<ns1:Login id="page_login" visible="true"></ns1:Login>
```

Now i want to change the visibility from true to false, from the login component. Is there a way to do this kind of interaction?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From within `Login`, you'd just set `visible`:

```
this.visible = false;
this.includeInLayout = false; // you may want this as well, depending on your ui
```

From within the parent, you could set `visible` directly:

```
page_login.visible = false;
```

or you could bind visible to some other property:

```
// in Script
[Bindable]
var loginVisible:Boolean = true;
...
// in MXML
<ns1:Login visible="{loginVisible}" />
```